# Downloading PDF file with GET request okhttp error

Tags: java, android, get, retrofit2, okhttp

fellow community!

So I have this simple request **using Retrofit 2**

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/pdf")
@GET("endpoint/download/{id}")
Call<ResponseBody> downloadPdf(@Header("Authorization") String accessToken, @Path("id") int id);
```

**I've laso tried to add @Streaming annotation**

Which should trigger web server and start download

**I am always getting error HTTP FAILED**: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{server_ip_here , proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=/server_ip_address cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}

Do you have some library to recommend or some clues why this is happening?

**Thank you**

Comment: you ever solve this?

Comment: @MidasLefko, yes I did. The general case should have worked, the problem was on the backend I guess (they never told me).

Unfortunately, I can't share any code since I am not working on that project anymore.